# Print a tree in a String in Java

Tags: java, tree

This code prints a tree like a want, but i need to make a string with the exact print. So the functions will be string and no void. I put an example of my result with SYSO. It has to be recursive. The node has a inf, left, right. The function `visualitza()` prints the card. I also created a function `VisualitzaStr` that returns the card in a string.

[image]

**The code:**

```
private void print2DUtil(NodeA root, int space, String dir) {
        // Base case
        if (root == null){
            return;
        }
            
        space += COUNT;
        for (int i = COUNT; i < space; i++)System.out.print(" ");
        Carta aux = root.inf;
        if (root.drt != null && root.esq != null) {
            if (root.drt.inf == null && root.esq.inf == null) {
                root.drt = null;
                root.esq = null;
            }
        }
        if (aux == null){
            System.out.println("No té fill" + dir+"\n");
        }
            
        else {
            aux.visualitza();
            System.out.println();
        }
        print2DUtil(root.drt, space, " Dreta");
        print2DUtil(root.esq, space, " Esquerra");
        return ;
    }

    // Wrapper over print2DUtil()
    public void print2D() {
        String str = "";
        // Pass initial space count as 0
        print2DUtil(this.arrel, 0, "");
    }
}
```

**The example in code:**

```
AS de COPES 
          SET de BASTONS    
                    SIS de COPES    
                              SIS de ESPASES    
                              AS de OROS    
                    AS de ESPASES   
                              CINC de OROS  
                              TRES de COPES 
          SET de COPES  
                    QUATRE de OROS  
                              AS de BASTONS 
                              CINC de COPES 
                    TRES de BASTONS 
                              DOS de COPES  
                              CABALL de OROS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it would be easiest to use a PrintWriter instead of System.out.
This cannot any longer be a global variable (like System.out) but must be an extra parameter.

```
print2DUtil(root, space, dir, new PrintWriter(System.out));

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(),
try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(sw)) {
    print2DUtil(root, space, dir, out);
}
String Sr sw.toString();

private void print2DUtil(NodeA root, int space, String dir, PrintWriter out) {
    ... out instead of System.out
```